# How to compare objects within an Array and output non matching object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How do you compare the objects in an array and output the object where the fields values does not match the other objects (ignoring the id field). How would this be done in Javascript, ES6 or Lodash?

**Things you should know**: Input array should be of any length, objects can have other fields but ignored when being compared. Should output the odd object out, or if there is no majority then output all objects.

```
const array1 = [{_id:'1', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}, 
               {_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true}, 
               {_id:'3', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}]

const array2 = [{_id:'1', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}, 
                {_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true}, 
                {_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true},
                {_id:'3', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}]

// expected array1 outcome:
{_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true}

// expected array2 outcome:
[{_id:'1', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}, 
 {_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true}, 
 {_id:'2', cow: false, sheep: true, pig: true},
 {_id:'3', cow: true, sheep: true, pig: false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function diff(array) {
  const m = new Map();

  for (const {cow, sheep, pig} of array) {
    const str = `${cow}${sheep}${pig}`;
    m.set(str, (m.get(str) || 0) + 1);
  }
  
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const {cow, sheep, pig} = array[i];
    const str = `${cow}${sheep}${pig}`;
    if (m.get(str) == 1) {
      result.push(array[i])
    }
  }

  if (result.length) {
    return result;
  }
  return array;
}
```